# Get checkbox selection of a dynamic table

Tags: java, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

first of all, I am very sorry to ask that question because I know kind of this already exist. But my search with google leads me to answer with angular, JavaScript and plenty other different techs, so I unfortunately cannot find a working answer and I hope you can help me. I am totally new to HTML, and everything with webdev. I use Java with Spring MVC, Thymleaf, have JQuery and Bootstrap dependencies.

I wrote a simple HTMl file [image]

As you can see below the table there is a "Delete Product button"

I just want that the user can select 1 to many products and if he clicks on delete the Rest Service should delete the elements and refresh the site.

What is not working:

The program doesn't receive the selection with the connected product.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container" >
    <h3>Fill form and execute changes</h3>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Old price</th>
                <th>Fee</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Select</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <!--/*@thymesVar id="productList" type="java.util.List"*/-->
            <tr th:each="product : ${productList}">
                <td th:text="${product.getProductName()}">ProductName</td>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="getTradableBTC" type="java.lang.Double"*/-->
                <td th:text="${product.getPrice()}">></td>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="getTop" type="java.lang.Double"*/-->
                <td th:text="${product.getOldPrice()}">></td>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="getBottom" type="java.lang.Double"*/-->
                <td th:text="${product.getFee()}">></td>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="getCurrencyName" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <td><a href="#" th:href="'exchange/edit/' + *{product.getProductName()}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox" value=""/>
                    </label>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <a th:href="'addproduct'" href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Add Product</a>

        <a th:href="deleteproduct" href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Delete Products</a>


    </div>
</div>
```

Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Post the JS code you have tried. --- And it looks like you are using the same `id` multiple times on the checkbox.

Comment: if you use form-post/get, then your `input` needs a `name`-attribute and must be descendant of the `form`-tag